# Is there a programmatic solution to suppress "This is a non-secure form" message, perhaps with JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, forms, ssl

I have a page that is called via SSL.  On this page is a form which is submitted via non-SSL.  The problem is when I submit the form, I get the following pop-up message:

> This is a non-secure form.
>
> This form will be sent in a way that is not secure.  Are you sure you want to send it?

I am submitting this form in JavaScript; is there a way to suppress this message programmatically?

Comment: No, and there never will be.  It's a security issue.

Comment: Thank you.  Is it because it's form data or because I'm using POST?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, and there never will be. It's a security issue.

If there were, people could use it to trick people into submitting malicious forms.

The only way to programmatically suppress the message would be to rewrite enough of your application that the form was no longer insecure.

Comment: Thank you.  That makes sense.  Is the message appearing because it's form data?  If I submit the data using ajax or through GET, will that change anything?

Comment: I don't know much about ajax but I'm inclined to say it won't.  I know using GET won't help.